# Override Element.style on iframe

Tags: css, iframe, styling

I have searched the site and found a lot of helpful material on the matter however I still cannot get this to work.

I am using a shipping plugin for my e-commerce site and I am simply trying to expand a box but it has an element.style attached and I cannot get any type of override to work, I tried !important and several other things but I cannot figure out what I am missing

Any help would be fantastic, thank you guys so much

[element styling help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsJLY.jpg)

Comment: Do some research then check ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com) what problem are you facing... include your source code(what you tried)

Answer (score 1):

As I know there is only possible way to do this is with Javascript and only if you are on same domain name as iframe, in other ways its called cross site scripting, and modern browsers block this type to behaviour.